# How to click an <li> and it displays selected classes

Tags: javascript, html-lists

With the below code what is required so when I click all,north,east,south or west that only the images associated with those classes are shown

```
<ul>
<li>All</li>
<li>North</li>
<li>East</li>
<li>South</li>
<li>West</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
<div><img src="image1" class="north all"></div>
<div><img src="image2" class="east all"></div>
<div><img src="image3" class="south all"></div>
<div><img src="image4" class="west all"></div>
<div><img src="image5" class="west all"></div>
<div><img src="image6" class="north all"></div>
<div><img src="image7" class="south all"></div>
<div><img src="image8" class="south all"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Search, research, hard work ( well not so hard ) and dedication + a bit of javaScript . Also, is `container` a HTML tag ?

Comment: You can use pure CSS, pure JS or even some JS libraries to perform this, have you got any restriction ?

Comment: Well I was intending on researching by starting here to learn what to research :) Is there a term for what I would search to learn and implement? Css would be my preferance so I could learn to do but I would imagine some JS would look best when the classes swap over

Comment: well. You could use an `accordion` or `tabs`. Search jQuery UI to understand the basics and you should write it in simple javascript if possible, if not, use jQuery.

Comment: After some tries, the solution in a pure css way is possible but kinda difficult, I recommend you to use JS like in the the answer provided by @Gio Ghviniashvili.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')

for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var item = list[i];
  item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var cl = e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    if (cl != 'all') {
      var all = document.querySelectorAll('.all')
      for (let j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
        let a = all[j];
        a.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    var all = document.querySelectorAll('.' + cl)
      for (let j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
        let a = all[j];
        a.style.display = 'block';
      }
  })
}
```

```css
.all {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
<li>All</li>
<li>North</li>
<li>East</li>
<li>South</li>
<li>West</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div><img src="image1" class="north all"></div>
  <div><img src="image2" class="east all"></div>
  <div><img src="image3" class="south all"></div>
  <div><img src="image4" class="west all"></div>
  <div><img src="image5" class="west all"></div>
  <div><img src="image6" class="north all"></div>
  <div><img src="image7" class="south all"></div>
  <div><img src="image8" class="south all"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much, I am yet to learn JS after html and css, this seems to work for what I need to begin with and have saved me some time and effort, champion

Comment: One question sorry, the images are keeping their original position, for example if I select north and the first north image was on the second row when I select north it remains there, what can be done so each selection starts at row 1 position 1?

Answer (score 0):

Class names can't have spaces in them. What you have there is two classes:
The div has two classes: north and all etc.
I am assuming you want to work with one class.
So, below is the modified code of yours.
I thing it might help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $( ".container" ).hide();

            $(".all").click(function(){               
                $( ".container" ).show();
                $( ".northall" ).show();
                $( ".eastall" ).show();
                $( ".southall" ).show();
                $( ".westall" ).show();
            });
            $(".north").click(function(){               
                $( ".northall" ).show();
                $( ".container" ).show();
                
                $( ".eastall" ).hide();
                $( ".southall" ).hide();
                $( ".westall" ).hide();
            });
            $(".east").click(function(){                
                $( ".eastall" ).show();
                $( ".container" ).show();
                
                $( ".southall" ).hide();
                $( ".westall" ).hide();
                $( ".northall" ).hide();
            });
            $(".south").click(function(){                
                $( ".southall" ).show();
                $( ".container" ).show();

                $( ".eastall" ).hide();
                $( ".westall" ).hide();
                $( ".northall" ).hide();
            });
            $(".west").click(function(){               
                $( ".westall" ).show();
                $( ".container" ).show();

                $( ".eastall" ).hide();
                $( ".southall" ).hide();
                $( ".northall" ).hide();
            });            
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stack overflow </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="all"><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li class="north"><a href="#">North</a></li>
        <li class="east"><a href="#">East</a></li>
        <li class="south"><a href="#">South</a></li>
        <li class="west"><a href="#">West</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="container">
        <div><img src="image1" class="northall"></div>
        <div><img src="image2" class="eastall"></div>
        <div><img src="image3" class="southall"></div>
        <div><img src="image4" class="westall"></div>
        <div><img src="image5" class="westall"></div>
        <div><img src="image6" class="northall"></div>
        <div><img src="image7" class="southall"></div>
        <div><img src="image8" class="southall"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this did work, the space was intended for 2 classes, one for north east south west and the other if all was selected

Comment: great to be helped.
if this answer solved your problem please mark as answered.
thank you.